# React Native Production Build Error ('Build input file cannot be found: {path}ExpoModulesProvider.swift')

Tags: xcode, react-native, production

So I finished a React Native project and trying to get it into production mode. However, XCode is throwing me this error saying that it cannot find ExpoModulesProvider.swift

Here is the full error,

I have been trying to solve this error the past 2-3 hours. I searched everywhere however, I could't find anything related to this error. Even StackOverFlow doesn't have it.

Thank you

[image: XCode Error]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and in my case I solved it by removing the `ExpoModulesProvider.swift` source from *Compile Sources*

[image]

Comment: Your answer saved me after hours of debugging, thank you.

Comment: @wowandy what does this file do ?

Comment: @Achraf This file is needed if you have an expo project. I migrated to a bare project a long time ago, so I don't need it