# Build input file cannot be found {PATH} did you forget to declare this file as an output

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, build

After creating and deleting the Objective-C file with the header, an error appeared. How can I fix it?

> error build: Build input file cannot be found:
> '/Users/iiiivaska/Desktop/To-Do List/To-Do List/View/Cells/To-Do List-Bridging-Header.h'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you have moved bridging file to other folder and Xcode compiler can not find it. Try to move this file in the top of your files tree

Comment: I just delete this file

Comment: Compiler tries to use this file, but can not find it. You have to delete this file from your project settings. To do this follow this steps:
1. open your project settings
2. select your target
3. open tab "Build settings"
4. find field with name "Objective-C Bridging Header" (you can use search in the top right corner)
5. remove text from this field

Comment: In my case `Objective-C Bridging Header` is empty @OleksandrBielov

Comment: The error was caused by excluding the arm64 architecture for the new target.
Xcode added `arm64` automatically to the Excluded Architectures. After removing its started working. 

1. In the Navigator sidebar select your project target.
2. Go to Build settings and search for `Excluded Architectures`.
3. Double-click on the corresponding row and remove the `arm64` architecture

Comment: yes, it helps me. Bridging-header should be placed not in AppName folder with .swift files, but under

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue but I just forgot to run "pod install" after some manipulation with project deps:-)

Comment: this helped me when I was very sleepy.....thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please, make sure from your path on build setting section.

1-  [Go to target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HE0C.png)

2- check deployment section => deployment assets to be "your path/Preview Content"

3- check packaging section => Info.plist file to be "your path/Info.plist"

4- signing section => Code Signing Entitlements to be "your path only"

Answer (score 1):

Happened with my Flutter app:

> ../Pods/Mantle/Mantle/NSDictionary+MTLMappingAdditions.m Build input
> file cannot be found:
> ../ios/Pods/Mantle/Mantle/NSDictionary+MTLMappingAdditions.m'. Did you
> forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom
> build rule which produces it?

Seems like it is just pod related false error message of XCode. After spending quite considerable time to debug it, the solution was to use these Flutter commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by closing the simulator that I had running

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check the compile sources section and if the file pointed out in the error is greyed out remove it. This solved it for me.

Based on this previous answer:
[React Native Production Build Error ('Build input file cannot be found: {path}ExpoModulesProvider.swift')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872943/react-native-production-build-error-build-input-file-cannot-be-found-pathex)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35463559)